# Error 404 in symfony 2 web forlder

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-404, assets

I wanted to add stylesheet with a variable inside

```
{% stylesheets combine=true
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/*'
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/XXX/css/*'
    '@CramifCramifKitBundle/Resources/public/jquery/css/' ~ jquery_theme ~ '/jquery-ui-1.1.10.custom.min.css'
    filter='cssembed'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

but it is not possible to put variables in the {% stylesheets %} block.

so I decided to do that way :

```
{% stylesheets combine=true
    '@CramifCramifKitBundle/Resources/public/css/*'
    '@CramifCramifKitBundle/Resources/public/JQMenu/css/*'
    filter='cssembed'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/jquery/css/' ~ jquery_theme ~ '/jquery-ui-1.1.10.custom.min.css') }}" />
```

of course I ran the command line : assets:install

The resources are in the web/bundles/mybundle folder, no problem

The problem is that the server returns a 404 error (the path is right thugh). More than that, when I type in the browser the url even to the bundles folder under web, same error 404

Maybe you can tell me another way to load css with dynamic paths

Comment: which resources return 404 error ?

Comment: obviously all the resources that are in the web folder... so in that case the jquery-ui-1.1.10.custom.min.css because the other resources are taken in the public folder of the bundle

Comment: Does this happen in all environments? Do you use controller to access assets (`use_controller` option in assetic configuration)? Have you tried to dump assets with `assetic:dump` command?

Comment: I have tried to use assetic:dump, same thing happen...use_controller is false and it happens in all environments

Answer (score 0):

It's a known problem in Assetic :

try to replace `@BundleName/Resources/public/` by `bundles/names/{css, js, images or whatever}/*`
in your `{% stylesheets %}` block

More informations here : https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/53#issuecomment-2523420

Comment: maybe I did not get it but I have no problem with the @BundleName/Resources/public .... my problem is when I get Resources from the web folder with the asset function

Comment: Did you try to make a symlink when you've installed your assets ?  `php app/console assets:install --symlink web`

Comment: same problem... I succeeded making it works by moving the .htaccess and put in back.  but everytime I run assetics:install... it comes back